# Why Hibernate in showing two different Queries in the console for single Query?`

Tags: java, hibernate

I am new to this Hibernate framework and using Hibernate 3 just to start using this framework.
I have a small module that is executing a update query.

```
public void saveProduct(Product prod) {
    String hql = "UPDATE Product set description = :description, price = :price,ctr=ctr+1 WHERE id = :id";
    Query query = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(hql);

    query.setParameter("description", prod.getDescription());
    query.setParameter("price", prod.getPrice());
    query.setParameter("id", prod.getId());

    logger.info(prod.toString());
    int result = query.executeUpdate();
    logger.info("Rows affected: " + result);
}
```

These are logs for this particular module and i have issue in this part hibernate is showing two different update queries one without column **ctr** and other one with column **ctr** or is it a normal behaviour:

```
May 23, 2016 5:55:37 PM com.mogae.dashboard.db.dao.ProductDaoImp saveProduct
    INFO: Description: test311;Price: 1.7279999999999998
    Hibernate:
        update
            products
        set
            description=?,
            price=?
        where
            id=?
    Hibernate:
        update
            products
        set
            description=?,
            price=?,
            ctr=ctr+1
        where
            id=?
    May 23, 2016 5:55:37 PM com.mogae.dashboard.db.dao.ProductDaoImp saveProduct
    INFO: Rows affected: 1
```

This is my xml configuration for DB connectivity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
         xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.0.xsd">

    <!-- the parent application context definition for the springapp application -->

    <aop:config>
        <aop:advisor pointcut="execution(* *..ProductManager.*(..))" advice-ref="txAdvice"/>
    </aop:config>

    <tx:advice id="txAdvice">
        <tx:attributes>
            <tx:method name="get*" read-only="true"/>
            <tx:method name="*"/>
        </tx:attributes>
    </tx:advice>

    <bean id="productDao" class="com.mogae.dashboard.db.dao.ProductDaoImp">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="mappingResources">
            <list>
                <value>product.hbm.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${db.driver}"/>
        <property name="url" value="${db.url}"/>
        <property name="username"  value="${db.user}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${db.password}"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:db.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

and this is my hibernate mapping file :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!DOCTYPE   hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.mogae.dashboard.actions.domain.Product" table="products" lazy="false">
        <id name="id" column="id" type="int">
            <generator class="native">
                <param name="sequence">products_id_seq</param>
            </generator>
        </id>

        <property name="description" column="description" type="string" />
        <property name="price" column="price" type="double" />
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

and this is my entity (Product) class:

```
   package com.mogae.dashboard.actions.domain;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Product implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public String toString() {
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        buffer.append("Description: " + description + ";");
        buffer.append("Price: " + price);
        return buffer.toString();
    }

    private String description;
    private Double price;
    private int id;

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(Double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Please help i have been searching for this issue on the google and various hibernate forums but haven't found one.

Comment: Your `Product` is a managed bean, changes are detected by hibernate. Now when you are manually executing the query the first thing hibernate does is to sync the in memory state with the database. Afterwards it executes your query. The basic problem is that you are trying to do the job hibernate should do. You are using an ORM tool then use it, don't write your  own queries for updates, just save the `Product`.

Comment: Thank You sir for clearing my doubt and it is now working as i have been expecting.